# Error in inserting data with JSON and Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json

I don't know where the problem is, my code looks fine and I tried hard, but getting error all the time.

Here is my code:

Markup:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Button1").click(function(){       
            var Name=document.getElementById('Text1').value
            var Class=document.getElementById('Text2').value
            var Data=JSON.stringify({Name:Name,Class:Class});
            alert(Data);       
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: 'Default.aspx/InsertData',
                data:Data,
                async: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#Text1').val('');
                    $('#Text2').val('');                 
                },
                error: function () { 
                    alert("Error") 
                }
            }); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

ASP.NET AJAX Page Method in code-behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public string InsertData(string Name, string Class)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into employee(EmployeeName,Class) values(@EmpName,@Classs)",con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", Name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Classs",Class);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    return "True";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods must be `static`, change your code to this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string InsertData(string Name, string Class)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into employee(EmployeeName,Class) values(@EmpName,@Classs)",con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", Name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Classs",Class);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    return "True";
}
```

Read [Why do ASP.NET AJAX page methods have to be static?](http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/) for an explanation as to why.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to stringify it.

Without stringifying just pass

```
"{'Name':'"+Name+"','Class':'"+Class+"'}"
```

If you want to pass the stringified object it must be as shown below

```
 JSON.stringify({'Name':Name,'Class':Class});
```

See the Quotes added.

```
var Data=JSON.stringify({'Name':Name,'Class':Class});
        alert(Data);       
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'Default.aspx/InsertData',
        data:Data,
        async: false,
         success: function (response) {
                             $('#Text1').val('');
                             $('#Text2').val('');

                         },
                         error: function ()
                         { alert("Error") }
        });
```

And in the page back code

```
    [WebMethod]
        public string InsertData(myobj getdat)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into employee(EmployeeName,Class) values(@EmpName,@Classs)",con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", getdat.Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Classs",getdat.Class);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            return "True";
        }
public class myobj
{
public string Name {get;set;}
public string Class{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Method must be **static** if it is in aspx page code behind

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string InsertData(string Name, string Class)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into employee(EmployeeName,Class) values(@EmpName,@Classs)",con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Classs",Class);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        return "True";
    }
```